# Clear Contents of Visible Cells in Filtered Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm filtering on a helper cell to locate cells in column B that need the contents cleared.  Once I filter on the helper cell that has identified cells in column B that need contents cleared, I am having issues clearing the contents in that cell.

I got the general idea down except I cannot figure out how to clear the visible cells only starting from the first visible cell down to the last visible cell.  My issue is identifying where is the start of the first visible cell after the filter is applied and where is the last visible cell.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell1 As Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

'This identifying the row of the last cell to filter on
Const WHAT_TO_FIND1 As String = "Tango"
Set FoundCell1 = ws.Range("AX:AX").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND1)


'This is filtering on the helper cell to determine what cells need to be cleared.
ws.Range("$BA$8:$BA$" & FoundCell1.Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "Delete"

'This is where I'm having issues.  I would like to replace B2 with a more dynamic code 
'that finds the first visible cell after the filter is applied and start there.  
'I think the xlUp solves the issue of finding the last visible cell but I am not sure 
'if that is the best or correct method.
ws.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell1 As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    'This identifying the row of the last cell to filter on
    Const WHAT_TO_FIND1 As String = "Tango"
    Set FoundCell1 = ws.Range("AX:AX").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND1)
    If FoundCell1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'WHAT_TO_FIND1 not found

    'This is filtering on the helper cell to determine what cells need to be cleared.
    With ws.Range("$BA$8:$BA$" & FoundCell1.Row)
        If .Row < 8 Or .Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub   'No data

        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Delete"
        On Error Resume Next    'Suppress error in case there are no visible cells
        Intersect(.Worksheet.Columns("B"), .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0         'Remove "On Error Resume Next" condition
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code Tiger.  I tried your code and it seems like the Autofilter is filtering on Column A instead of BA...which doesn't make sense because the code looks to be referencing BA.  I had this issue earlier too where I referenced BA to be filtered but it kept filtering A.  I thought it was just my code at first but is this a glitch in Excel?

Comment: @JDoe I am unable to replicate that behavior.  It correctly filters column BA for me.

Comment: Ah I got it, it was my issue.  There was an empty row separating the header from the rest of the cells in the helper row causing this issue.  I just had to insert content in the empty row to connect the header to the rest of the data in the helper column and your macro ran perfectly.  Thank you very much!